# Why does AC charge the capacitor?

Tags: capacitor-charging

I know that capacitors charge and discharge at the same rate. As the total the there will be no charge or no energy stored.  When I connect a fan capacitor to the AC home source for few seconds and I unplug it and then I short two terminals it discharges. How it is possible if the charging rate and discharging rate are same?

Comment: "*capacitor charges and discharges at the same rate.*" Can you give a source that proves this ? Capacitors can charge and discharge at different rates depending on external circuitry connected to it.

Comment: "*when I connect the fan capacitor to the Ac home source*". It is dangerous to do this.

Comment: "*i unplug it*". If you unplug while the AC voltage was high (non zero), the capacitor retains the charge inside it and it could not discharge in the next half cycle of AC due to being unplugged. This charge got *discharged* when you shorted the terminals.

Comment: @AJN: That's a good start on an answer. You should post it as such.

Answer (score 3):

AC supply consists of positive voltage half cycles followed by negative voltage half cycles. During the positive voltage cycles, the capacitor gets charged to a positive voltage. During negative cycles the capacitor gets charged to a negative voltage. In between, there will be some time instants where the capacitor gets discharged to zero volts (when the AC supply passes through zero volts).

If you unplug a capacitor while the AC was some non zero voltage, the capacitor retains the charge and the voltage just before un-plugging.
When you then short the terminals, the stored charges gets a path and the capacitor discharges; usually accompanied by a spark if the voltage was high.

### Note

The charging rate and discharging rate of a capacitor depends on the external circuit connected to it. At any given time instant the capacitor is either charging or discharging or holding its charge; but not charging and discharging at the same time instant.

## Warning

Directly plugging the leads of a fan capacitor to AC supply is **dangerous**. The capacitors usually have a metallic body and any damaged capacitor can allow the AC supply to be conducted to this metal body. If you are holding the capacitor with bare hands, you can get a serious shock from the supply. Even if the capacitor is good, accidentally touching the leads can also shock you.